# matplotlib invisible bar if height is zero

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting a bar graph without axes.  I'd like to only show bars with non-zero values.  If it is zero, I want no bar at all.  Currently it will show a tiny line at the zero axis, I want  that to disappear.  How can I do that?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (0, 1890,865, 236, 6, 1, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0)
ind = range(len(data))
width = 0.9   # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, data, width)
plt.xlabel('Duration 2^x')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('DBFSwrite')
plt.axis([0, len(data), -1, max(data)])

ax = plt.gca()

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('myfig')
```

[image: Sample output]

See the very thin lines at x=0 and x=7-16?  I'd like to eliminate those.

Comment: You should *include the code* you have so far!

Comment: Good idea, I've added code and sample output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s arrays, and create a mask which you can use to filter out the indices where `data` has value 0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([0, 1890,865, 236, 6, 1, 2, 0 , 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0])
ind = np.arange(len(data))
width = 0.9   # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

mask = data.nonzero()

p1 = plt.bar(ind[mask], data[mask], width)
plt.xlabel('Duration 2^x')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('DBFSwrite')
plt.axis([0, len(data), -1, max(data)])

ax = plt.gca()

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('myfig')
```

[image]